# Responsive design of my menu and IE problem

Tags: internet-explorer, menu, responsive

I have a problem with the responsive design of my menu. I set the text buttons of the menu to shrink at certain pixels, but it doesn't go smoothly.
Therefore, the words in the menu are arranged in several lines.

1. How the text can be reduced in proportion by reducing the screen of the browser smoothly in one line to 600 pixels? 
   Then the "hamburger" menu icon should appear if the pixels are less than 600.

in jsfiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/h7wrtsbo/

2. When I open with Internet Explorer (11) on the left and right gives gray squares. I have set in every page :

   `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"/>`

... but this is clearly not enough.Is there is any way to correct this?

example - https://imgshare.io/image/7wFeS

Thank you in advance.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>



HTML:


<div id="navbaronder">
<div class="topnav unselectable" id="myTopnav">
    <div id="center1">
   <div id="center2">
       <div class="underline">
       <div id="container2">

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Sales &amp; Marketing</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="sales#sale" style="text-decoration:none">Sales</a>
<a href="sales#marketing" style="text-decoration:none">Marketing</a>
<a href="sales#smmarketing" style="text-decoration:none">Social Media Marketing</a>
<a href="sales#smmanagement" style="text-decoration:none">Social Media Management</a>
</div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Administratie &amp; Accounting</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">Administratie</a>
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">Boekhouding &amp; Example</a>
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">Financieel Advies</a>
</div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Exaple &amp; Example</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">

</div>
</div>



<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Logistiek &amp; Example</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">

</div>
</div>



<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Drone Fotografie &amp; Videografie</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">

</div>
</div>



<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Opleidingen &amp; Cursussen</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">

</div>
</div>


  <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a><!-- golemina na butona --> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


SCRIPT:

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}


 CSS: 


/*********************************************************************************/
/* SERVICES MENU                                                                 */
/*********************************************************************************/


/* menu+submenu*/
#navbaronder {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin: 155px 0px 0px 0px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 500;
  outline: 0;
}

/*********************************************************************************/
/* UNSELECTABLE                                                                  */
/*********************************************************************************/

.unselectable {            
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}

img::selection {         
    background: transparent;

}


/*********************************************************************************/
/* ANIMATING LINK UNDERLINES                                                     */
/*********************************************************************************/


.underline > a, button  {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: white;
}

.underline > a, button:hover {
  color: white;
}

.underline > a, button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.underline > a, button:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}


/*********************************************************************************/
/* DROP DOWN            MENU                                                     */
/*********************************************************************************/

body {margin:0;}

.topnav {

  background-color: #dddddd;  

}
#center1 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;

}

#center2 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}



.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 8px; /
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px; 
}

.topnav .icon {  
  display: none;
  color:#2654BA;
}

.dropdown {    
  float: left; 
  position:relative; /

}


.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;   
  padding: 6px 20px; 
  background-color: inherit; 
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;


}

.dropdown-content { 
  display: none;   
  position: absolute;  

  top:100%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);

  background-color: #f9f9f9;    
  min-width: 220px;      
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;   

}


 .dropdown-content a {  
  float: none;    
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 8px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center; 
  background-color:#f1f1f1; 

}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn { 
  background-color:transparent; 
  color: #2651AB;

}

.dropdown-content a:hover { 
  background-color: #ddd; 
  color: black;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { 
  display:block;

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1440px) and (min-width: 1024px)  {
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:100%;   
  font-size:160%;
  padding: 6px 18px;
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:100%;   
  font-size:130%;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 600px) {
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:100%;   
  font-size:100%;
  padding: 6px 9px;
  }
}


/* hambutger icona */


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How the text can be reduced in proportion by reducing the screen of
>   the browser smoothly in one line to 600 pixels? Then the "hamburger"
>   menu icon should appear if the pixels are less than 600.

You could use the "vw" unit to set the font size.

The vw unit, which means the "viewport width". By using this way, the text size will follow the size of the browser window. You could refer to the following code sample:

```
<p style="font-size:2vw;">Resize the browser window to see how the text size scales.</p>
```

the result as below:

[image]

> When I open with Internet Explorer (11) on the left and right gives
>   gray squares. I have set in every page :

As for this issue, I think the issue is related to the following code:

```
#center1 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;

}

#center2 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

Try to remove the left property, then, using the following code:

```
    #center1 {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        /*left: 50%;*/
        width:100%;
    }

    #center2 {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        /*left: -50%;*/
    }
```

The result like this:

[image]

Besides, as we can see that it contains blank zone at the head of the Top navigation bar, if you want to remove it, try to modify the following code:

```
    /* menu+submenu*/
    #navbaronder {
        background-color: #dddddd;
        margin: 155px 0px 0px 0px;
        transition: 0.4s;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 500;
        outline: 0;
    }
```

to (change the margin property):

```
    /* menu+submenu*/
    #navbaronder {
        background-color: #dddddd;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        transition: 0.4s;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 500;
        outline: 0;
    }
```

Finally, the output as below:

[image]

At the end, here is an sample code about [how to create Responsive Navbar with Dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp), you could refer to it.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.

When I set up "vw" unit (font-size: 17px;  -->  font-size: 1.15vw;) to set the font size the text is either too big or too small.It should be max 17px and min 10px.
 

Maybe I should use calc ( + ) and @media screen and (min-width:1600px){}

,but I am new to this .


The problem with Internet Explorer is that the menu is only left-aligned. Is there a way to center it?

Тhe white space above the menu has a logo on the right and 3 buttons on the left but thanks for the additional information.

Comment: "the font size the text is either too big or too small", you could set the max font size according to the media rules. "The problem with Internet Explorer is that the menu is only left-aligned. Is there a way to center it?" About this issue, please check your previous code, when you are using the "left:50%;" property in the #center1 and #center2, it will center the menu in the IE browser. please check [it](https://imgshare.io/image/iefout.7wFeS).